# ASP.NET Core API - Posting List<string> from swagger UI received as single string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

***My Setup***

- Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web API
- Swagger UI

***Problem***

This is a piece of the request object

```
public class CreatePostRequest       
{
        public long? EventTime { get; set; }

        public long? EndTime { get; set; }

        public List<string>? Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I submit something like this:
[image]

And in the controller, I receive them as one string

This is the controller:

```
        [HttpPost(ApiRoutes.Posts.Create)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Response<CreatePostResponse>), 201)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]CreatePostRequest postRequest)
        {
           // postRequest.Tags.Count == 1 -> both in the first list element separated by coma
        }
```

I need them to be received as 2 separate strings. I thing the problem might be with model binding but not sure.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it important for you to use [FromForm] attribute?. I would try to remove the attribute and add [ApiController] above the controller class. It will enable you to have standard Web API bindings.

Comment: @klucyszy Ok, [ApiController] didn't help, I need [FromFrom] bc I have some IFormFile inputs

Comment: I replicated your issues. It looks like a bug in Swagger UI. I do not have that issue using Postman.

Comment: @klucyszy yeah, works for me too in postman. I guess I will leave it like this then.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this using .NET 6 Web API.
Below is the working solution with screenshot attached:
[image: Simple Working Example]

This picture is of Swagger UI for input parameters:
[image: Swagger UI Example]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too

The information was received correctly when I submitted the request with swagger

But when it was sent from frontend, I got an error

You can do this :

Model :

```
Public string MyTagList {get;set;}
```

Controller :

```
List<string> tagList=MyTagList.Split("-").ToList();
```

Posted Data From frontEnd:

```
myTagList:"tag1-tag2-tag3-tag4"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CreatePostRequest       
{
        public long? EventTime { get; set; }

        public long? EndTime { get; set; }
       ///<example>["First String","Secound String"]</example>

        public List<string>? Tags { get; set; }
}
```